# Typescript assertion for hasOwnProperty?

Tags: typescript

Is there a useful `asserts` I could add to this function?

```
function assertOwnProperty(obj: object, property: string): asserts ??? {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    throw new Error(`Expected object to have property ${property}`)
  }
}
```

Thanks : )

--- update

The goal here is, given an object of unknown type, to be able to assert that a given property exists, and have the type system knows it, e.g.

```
let obj = JSON.parse("{a: 1}") as object
obj.a // type error
assertOwnProperty(obj, "a")
obj.a // not type error (because unreachable unless .a exists)
```

Comment: Could you please share more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type with a dynamic key check

```
function assertOwnProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, property: K) {
  if (typeof obj === "object" && !(obj as Object).hasOwnProperty(property)) 
  {
    throw new Error(`Expected object to have property ${property}`)
  }
}

type YourType = {
  name: string
}

const test: YourType = {
  name: "test"
}
assertOwnProperty(test, "name")
assertOwnProperty(test, "name1") //error due to not existing in YourType
```

You can check [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBDAzhgpgJ1gPIDukACrogA56wCeAPACoA0KA0itgB6zaQAmGFAGtstRKBSMAfAApEAIwBWALimtKFavlpq2AShQBvYChTxJsutQkpFSlAF5nKAET3scVygBkPlACE8sroQgTKnrD6AHQAFpjEZFo0tLKaVCn6hiZmZrCxFEQokNhFAKK4FLiyAAZlXNRw2Px2EXAosIgo8QBu2Cjp2nQoACRGgykAvjX6piiTwAvA1v0AmojguIy01E7Gc5BoALbYahiwuPCQAOaLINDI5x3Y52rrm9u7jvtmhydqrl451cd0wOHwiXIGR0VhesFYrj%202FcszBNEhyRhQPhbiRAEYUSgAPREvBVIA)

Comment: Thanks. This is not quite what I was after but I realise now the question was not at all clear, I've updated it.

Comment: I feel like you're overthinking it (perhaps I don't know your whole situation). If you have JSON data in which you know the data format, why you don't try to assert it like `let obj: YourType = JSON.parse("{a: 1}")`? @TomLocke

Comment: Yeah I get that but my situation is more complicated. I need the assertOwnProperty for security reasons validating unknown input from the network. It's not something I'm stuck with, I was just curious if there was a way to assert something like that.

Comment: `validating unknown input from the network` You're already good with `hasOwnProperty ` during run-time. If it's an unknown input, we have nothing to deal with Typescript which only asserts your types during build-time @TomLocke